Consecutive numbers
Are there ever more consecutive composite numbers than there are primes up to that point? I imagine not, because the primes are the ones which cancel out multiples, so will inevitably have to fill in the gaps between multiples of them. Then again, the number of combinations possible grows faster than an exponential. It may be a matter of calculating how many products are within certain bounds. Additionally, I have that there is a known set of composite numbers, an infinite union of sets described by an arithmetic sequence. $\{9+6x\}\cup\{15+10x\}\cup\{21+14x\}\cup\{33+22x\}\cup\{39+26x\}\cup...$
which when removed from the odd numbers yields the prime numbers. Conversely, if we show that there is a point that many of these terms are lining up with common difference 2 we have shown some progress on the result.

prime gaps stay small. All that is proved is along the lines of:  the next prime bigger than $p$  is smaller than $p +  p^{0.6} $  As fas as has benn checked by computer, for $p \geq 11,$  the next larger prime is smaller than $p + \log^2 p,$  this being natural log.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap  and: "The Cramér–Shanks–Granville ratio is the ratio of gn / (ln(pn))2.[6] If we discard anomalously high values of the ratio for the primes 2, 3, 7, then the greatest known value of this ratio is 0.9206386 for the prime 1693182318746371. Other record terms can be found at OEIS: A111943."

https://oeis.org/A111943

What does this ratio really measure?

If I remember right , it was $p^{0.525}$ , but this is not significantly better.

The notion that prime gaps stay "small" requires context. If you know a prime number on the order of $10^{100}$, then the relationship says that there will be another prime somewhere in the next $\approx 10^{52}$ following integers. That may be small compared to the prime itself, but it is not small in terms of conventional appreciation of absolute size.

That's a fair point, and I wish there were some shortcuts for finding out how long the run of composites I mentioned will be. If we're just counting odd numbers, every third is a multiple of 3 and can be skipped. The same thing can be done for every prime, but it's tricky to say how often they're close, isn't it? Like multiples of 3 and 5 don't come close every 15 odd numbers, or something obvious. Quite interested in the bit about comparing length of prime gaps to prime count up to then.

@TalonEaglefeathers If we could do that exactly , we would have an efficient way to find primes. Noone has the slightest idea how this should work. If you mean the approximate prime gap : The actual gap will be much smaller than what we can guarantee with what is proven.

"Are there ever more consecutive composite numbers than there are primes up to that point" so Grimm's conjecture ?
